# Make a countdown from now to a date in the future[C#]

Tags: c#

Hello so i'm trying to make something like a countdown from the time now to a time in the future, therefor i initialize 5 new variables:

```
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year, currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month, currentDay = DateTime.Now.Day, currentHour = DateTime.Now.Hour, currentMinute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
```

so now i have f.e. a date in the future like 04.11.2016 11:14(Day.Month.Year Hour.Minute) so now i tried to just subtract those values but i ended up getting negative numbers and since i want a countdown looking like this: 
Years: 0000
Months: 00
Days: 00
Hours: 00
Minutes: 00
Seconds: 00
that's not really what i want to end up with. So i wanted to ask if there is an Object orientated way on how to do this, without using a ton of if statements? Thanks in advance

Comment: so how are you planning on counting down without a `Timer` also just posting that code is not enough information.. can you show what you actually have and or have tried besides posting the single line of code..?

Answer (score 1):

Use TimeSpan

```
DateTime dateInTheFuture = new DateTime(....);
TimeSpan ts = dateInTheFuture - DateTime.Now;
// e.g.
Console.WriteLine (ts.ToString());
```

Check [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`TimeSpan.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN for various formats

Answer (score 1):

Where the value within the DateTime.Parse is your final/end time:

```
TimeSpan t = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2016 05:00:01 AM") - DateTime.Now;
string output = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} Hours, {2} Minutes, {3} Seconds", 
    t.Days, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
```

You can simply extend the string.Format method if you'd like to add months and years.